# JavaScript load event execution sequence

Tags: jquery, firefox, dom-events

I have the following code:

```
//create a tab and active it
var tab = gBrowser.addTab("chrome://xxx/content/html/xxx.html");
gBrowser.selectedTab = tab
var newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(gBrowser.selectedTab);
newTabBrowser.addEventListener("load", function () {
    //event 1.          
    }, true);
```

where xxx.html has:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        //event 2
});
$(window).load(function(){
    //event 3
});
</script>
```

I understand that event 2 is fired before event 3.
And event 1 is fired before event 3 by place a `alert()`, can anyone explain me the reason of this. Or the sequence of 1 and 3 are unpredicted.

Comment: Quick question. `addEventListener` only binds the handler. Why is it getting triggered?

Comment: Please see:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about exactly what event 1 is - I'm guessing this is a Firefox plugin so it's actually triggering as soon as the tab itself loads rather than the document inside it.

Event 2 will fire as soon as the complete HTML DOM is ready, but before all external resources load (such as images and stylesheets).  Event 3 will only fire when all external resources have completed loading.

Comment: Event 1 is the Firefox plugin. The MDN Doc center explains that newTabBrowser.addEventListener("load", function (){}); is used "If you want to work on the content of the newly opened tab, you'll need to wait until the content has finished loading." I have the confusion of "the content has finished loading". If the content means HTML DOM and images and css, then I guess event 1 will fire before event 3 is because event 1 is binded first. Still not sure.